# Why is a pointer considered a compound type in C++?

Tags: c++

My understanding: Compound type is composed of primitive and other compound types. I understand that arrays, functions, classes, unions and enumerations are compound types. Why is a pointer a compound? What primitive types is it composed of?

Comment: It is composed from the type it points to.  There doesn't have to be more than one related primitive type, after all an array only has one element type and you don't have any difficulty accepting it as a compound.

Comment: "compound type" just means "type created with a built-in type builder". But then "type builder" isn't in the standard's vocabulary. And it would be verbose.

Comment: What about `Data* d = new Data`.. Isn't `d` a composite type? I mean, it's just indirection. It `points` to a composite type. A composite type can be constructed from the language's primitive types or other composite types. A pointer points to a primitive type or another composite type (pointer initialization can be see like construction).

Answer (score 6):

I believe the rationale can be found in the standard under "Basic concepts" (section 3 in C++14, for example):

> Finally, this clause presents the fundamental types of the language and lists the ways of constructing compound types from these.

Hence a compound type is really just a type created from another underlying type. A pointer certainly meets that definition since you construct `pointer-to-T` from `T`.

In terms of history, it's likely that this was carried over from C since it has the same concept, though it refers to the types and object/function and derived types. Derived types there seems to mirror the same things (at least those things that are common across both languages), including pointers.

Comment: Is the void pointer (`void*`) an exception? Because the void type is weird.

Comment: @PaulStelian: no, the standard specifically lists pointer-to-void as a compound type, possibly because it really means `pointer-to-anytype`. And there's nothing weird about the `void` type other than the fact it doesn't actually *exist* - you only have to try compile `void x;` to see that :-)

Comment: The void type exists as the return type of functions but not as anything else.

Comment: I'll clarify that comment a little, there's a note in the standard: A pointer to void does not have a pointer-to-object type, however, because void is not an object type.

Comment: @PaulStelian It actually shows up in a few other places. The language specifically excludes `void` from a lot of usages, but other than those exclusions, it is not a fundamentally different sort of thing than `bool` or `double`.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is compound type because it stores both a memory address and a data type. Answer from Murach’s C++ Programming book.

Answer (score -1):

Pointer point to different type is different, so pointer contain some information about the type it point to.And pointer has 2 special function at least, they are * and ->.

Of cause, int,char have some function, something different is that you just need to know "it is int" or "it is char" for those, but when you try using * or ->, knowing "it is pointer" and nothing is infeasible (and pointer++ need to know size of its type).

In fact, every thing in object-oriented method should be regarded as compound types(or we call it class more often) , because you always need to do something using data(otherwise, the existence of data makes no sense), if so, what you are try to do is suggested that appear as method in class, since it is OOM.